# Modify title of DropdownActions of ExtLib WidgetContainer

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Since there is no property for the ExtLib xe:widgetContainer's dropDownNodes action menu I wonder how to modify (or even calculate) the title attribute to get rid of the default text "click for actions". Do you have any idea to achieve a custom title text?
To illustrate what I mean please look at this: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/4184/ff.png

Comment: If not possible on the server, then consider using Dojo to fix it

Comment: Ok Per, that's a solution I can accept ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Got it working with that workaround from Per:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
var node = dojo.query(".lotusActionIcon").attr("title", "your custom title")    
})
```